# Google Play compliance violation "dismiss button not clearly visible"

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I recently published an update to an existing app which uses in-app subscriptions, and got the following rejection by Google Play app review:

> **Your app does not comply with the Subscriptions policy:**
>
> The dismiss button in your app is not clearly visible and users may not understand that they can access functionality without signing up for the free trial

The thing is, my app requires a subscription to work, so the rejection doesn't seem to make sense since there is no dismiss button at all. The screenshot they attached is of the the paywall in the app, which is shown at startup if the user doesn't have an active subscription.

I can't make sense of what they mean - is an app no longer allowed to put its entire functionality behind a subscription paywall? If I put a dismiss button on the paywall, it won't have any meaningful action - the only possible action for a dismiss button is to exit the app altogether...

Did anyone else get this rejection in an app which requires a subscription for ALL functionality?

Comment: This will probably be closed as off-topic but I am very curious to hear the outcome.

Comment: FWIW their help section says "In-app promotions that do not clearly demonstrate that a user can access content without a subscription (when available)."

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a mistake by Google App Review.

I appealed the rejection and explained that users can not access any content (except the paywall) without a subscription, and that a dismiss button makes no sense. 24 hours later I got an email back saying that my appeal was accepted, and I could resubmit the update. Another 24 hours later, the update was accepted and ready for publishing.